# count trailing zeros in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

OpenCL has a builtin function clz() to count the number of leading zeros of a `long`, `int`, etc. but nothing similar seems to be present for counting the number of trailing zeros. I've not been able to find any way to do this, other than just manually re-implementing of course. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
x & -x
```

leaves one least significant 1-bit. To get its position you can try something like:

```
32 - clz(x & -x)
```

Comment: actually it's `63-clz(x&-x)` for long and `31-clz(x&-x)` for int but thanks, that works!